# Print elements of object array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects to count element frequency in another array using for loop which prints correct output.

```
counts = {};
counter = 0;
counter_array = [50,50,0,200]; //this is just for example, this array is filled dynamically

for (var x = 0, y = counter_array.length; x < y; x++) {
    counts[counter_array[x]] = (counts[counter_array[x]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log('FREQUENCY: ',counts); //outputs FREQUENCY: {50:2, 0:1, 200:1}
```

There is another array of arrays:

```
holder_text_array = [["a",50,0],["b",0,0]]; //example of dynamically filled array
var p = "a";
var i = 0;
while(i < holder_text_array.length){
    if (holder_text_array[i][0]==p) {
        var s = counts[holder_text_array[i][1]];
        console.log('Element: ', holder_text_array[i][1]); //prints 50 for i = 0
        console.log('frequency: ',counts[s]); //prints undefined
        counter = counts[s];
    }
i++;
}
```

The array of arrays "holder_text_array" consists of elements whose frequency I need to get in the while loop. Can someone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: do you want the count of every object of all arrays or just the count of each array? please add the wanted result for the second (nested) array.

Comment: @NinaScholz I want to access frequency of 2nd element of multidimensional array which is stored in counts object array and set counter equal to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency is stored in `s` not in `counts[s]`

You're logging `counts[s]` where `var s = counts[holder_text_array[i][1]];`

You've already got the element from `counts` in `s`. Just log the value of `s`

Apart from that the function works!

```js
counts = {};
counter = 0;
counter_array = [50,50,0,200]; //this is just for example, this array is filled dynamically

for (var x = 0, y = counter_array.length; x < y; x++) {
    counts[counter_array[x]] = (counts[counter_array[x]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log('FREQUENCY: ',counts); //outputs FREQUENCY: {50:2, 0:1, 200:1}
holder_text_array = [["a",50,0],["b",0,0]]; //example of dynamically filled array
var p = "a";
var i = 0;
while(i < holder_text_array.length){
    if (holder_text_array[i][0]==p) {
        var s = counts[holder_text_array[i][1]];
        console.log('Element: ', holder_text_array[i][1]); //prints 50 for i = 0
        console.log('frequency: ', s); // CHANGED THIS TO JUST `s`
        counter = counts[s];
    }
i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes I was working on my code and later I matched it with your solution and this was the issue.

Comment: Thanks, glad you could figure it out yourself. Its the best way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and call the count function again for (nested) arrays with the same `counts` object.

The result contains the counts of each element.

```js
function getCounts(array, counts = {}) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const value = array[i];
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            getCounts(value, counts);
            continue;
        }
        if (!counts[value]) counts[value] = 0;
        counts[value]++;
    }
    return counts;
}


console.log(getCounts([["a", 50, 0], ["b", 0, 0]]));
```

Comment: I do not want frequency of nested array elements. I want to get frequency of counter array element which is equal to 2nd element of array in array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Issue is in initialization.
I changed the following:

```
var s = counts[holder_text_array[i][1]];
counter = counts[s];
```

It works this way:

```
var s = holder_text_array[i][1];
counter = counts[s];
```